# android returning function through JavascriptInterface

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to return a function through JavascriptInterface but am getting an error:

***Cannot refer to a non-final variable funct inside an inner class defined in a different method***

here is the code:

```
         public void androidFieldPrompt(String title, String msg, String funct) {
             final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);  
             AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);                 
             alert.setTitle(title);  
             alert.setMessage(msg);  
             alert.setView(input);
             alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  
                    String value = input.getText().toString();
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:window."+funct+"('"+value+"')");
                    return;                  
                   }  
                 });   
            alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
            alert.show();            
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all. The variable funct is not available in the scope of the anonymous event handler class:

That should do the trick:

```
 public void androidFieldPrompt(String title, String msg, final String funct) {
         final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);  
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);                 
         alert.setTitle(title);  
         alert.setMessage(msg);  
         alert.setView(input);
         alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  
                String value = input.getText().toString();
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:window."+funct+"('"+value+"')");
                return;                  
               }  
             });   
        alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
        alert.show();            
     }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in production with final var:  E/Web Console(26069): Uncaught TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function at null:1

Comment: @ushdiver add a log output before loading the URL. Something like Log.d("ASDF", "My funct: " + funct); Maybe the value is null.

Comment: I was sending through the method instead of just the name of the method on the javascript side    androidFieldPrompt('','Search the Help Database',promptResult); - changed to     androidFieldPrompt('','Search the Help Database','promptResult');   .  final did the trick after